# How do I connect the vertices of this geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I fix this so that the connecting part doesn't overlap or leave gaps in between?

[image]

[image]

The object consists only of edges, and the problem occurs when more than 2 vertices are connected.

This is how it looks when Geometry Nodes are applied.

[image]

The right bar is what I'm aiming for. As you can see, the edges are aligned with the cube in the corner:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know your mesh, so I can only make guesses, but you could solve this as follows:

1. First split the mesh into single edges.
2. Then calculate the length of the edges and scale them inwards according to the desired thickness.
3. Turn these edges into curves with `Mesh to Curve`, and then back into a mesh with `Curve to Mesh` and a profile.
4. Next, instantiate cubes at the vertices of the original mesh. This will give you the basic shape.
5. So that the cubes do not have unnecessary faces, remove them by creating a selection. If the faces are exactly on the endpoints of the scaled edges, then it is an inner face and you can delete it.
6. Finally, you just need to combine this geometry, and merge the duplicate points with `Merge by Distance`.

[image]

[image]

*PS: Of course, this technique only works for rectangular structures!*

Comment: just great!!!! +1

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your praise ...again! But let's see if the answer leads to the goal at all, or if it turns out again that the question was actually meant quite differently :D

Comment: The answer is great anyway and i think a lot of people can use it - including me!!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've been looking for, you are awsome :D

Comment: @quellenform Just one thing, how do you align or rather lock the rotation of the face at the end points with the cube at the connection point? Then it would be perfect for bevels.

Comment: @codedevil666 I'm not quite clear what you mean by that...can you please describe it a little more?

Comment: @quellenfrom sry, for my bad explanation, I'll post a picture. I am sure you'll know what I mean.