# How do I align the edges with the corner cubes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Sequel of: [Vertices are not connecting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270132/vertices-are-not-connecting)

Hello, I once again have a bit of problem with my geometry node. I want want to align the endpoint edges of the beams with corners, like the one on the right side, which I made by hand.

[image]

Here is the associated geometry node (credit: @quellenform):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I have an idea there and will take a closer look as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I can't come up with a 100% procedural solution here (at least not based on the previous technique). The solution is likely to be very individual, so I would ask you to share your blend file with us that contains the final mesh (and not just an example) that you want to use.

Comment: Sure, if you insist, I'll use this geometry node for all sorts of scaffolds. I have to create multiple objects of this kind, that's why I want to use geometry nodes, otherwise I would be quicker, if I do them by hand. I'll include a few objects parts which I'll use for my assets later. They aren't more complicated than the mesh I showed above.

Comment: I added a link underneath the images

Comment: OK, sorry, but I have to give up for now, because I don't have a solution. You have some parts in your mesh where 9 edges come together at one point, and they are aligned in all possible directions. There are hardly any right angles and so it is difficult to create a mesh with the current technique that gives a satisfying result. I'll think about it some more, but I really don't have a viable idea at the moment on how to solve this with *Geometry Nodes*. Sorry.

Comment: ok, no problem, thanks again for helping me. I'll let you know, if I or someone else can come up with a solution 

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is not a task for *Geometry Nodes* (at least I didn't manage to get a satisfying result with it).

But maybe you can get a halfway acceptable result with other modifiers:

1. Use the *Skin* modifier.
2. Adjust the scale of your object a little bit (scale the object and apply the scale with *Apply > Scale*). This changes the strength of the skin modifier.
3. Use the modifier *Decimate* to remove the unnecessary edges.

[image]

Comment: hmm, I'll give it a try, thanks alot!