# How can I transfer normal of cube edges to curve tilt?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, normals, vector

Here is my problem.
Ideally I want to procedually make frames like this.
[image]

I start with a default cube and [mest to curve] it into some curves. After I use a custom profile shape to [curve to mesh] the curve and set the tilt to the edge normal of the cube, I got this.

[image]
I think it is the tilt that im doing wrong.
All the edges are facing wrong direction and twisted, not even close to the edge normal of the original cube.
I might have the wrong understanding of how the tilt/normal/vector things work.

Can you help me to set up th node?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would have expected such an answer with your request and if you will be happy with it, but unfortunately there is no ready solution for this task in *Geometry Nodes*.

What I think you're looking for doesn't even exist as a standalone modifier, unfortunately, because the way I see it, you'd like a tool that converts the edges of a mesh into a wireframe with a profile.

Unfortunately there is no such (built-in) tool.

But maybe this node tree is a solution for you:

[image]

Here I calculate an angle per point based on the normals of the edges and the generated tangents and normals of the curves, with which I feed the node `Set Curve Tilt`.

...has become a bit complex, but I don't think it can be much simpler.

Also, with all these solutions you have the problem that it is hard to create a solid mesh (depending on the profile) and it also only works with a cube.

Maybe the following articles will help you with this topic:

- [Vertices are not connecting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270132)
- [How do I align the edges with the corner cubes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270220)

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>